# parse curl response data

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

Hey guys so i`m posting fields to a url,
the data returned by using a print $result shows like this (from view source in the browser)

```
    <html>
        <body>TransID=0&REFNO=&Auth=&AVSCode=&CVV2ResponseMsg=&Notes=Your merchant information is not correct.&User1=&User2=&User3=&User4=
        </body>
    </html>
```

there is 1 more empty row above the 
now i need to get those body pairs as an array so i can work with them..i`m not good with regex or stuff like that to get them..pls help

Comment: you want to parse html or just string between body tag ?

Comment: i only need the stuff between the <body>
TransID=0&REFNO=&Auth=&AVSCode=&CVV2ResponseMsg=&Notes=Your merchant information is not correct.&User1=&User2=&User3=&User4=


would be great if i have it as an array so i can work with it like
    $response['TransID'] $response['REFNO'] ... etc

Comment: `TransID=0&REFNO=&Auth=&AVSCode=&CVV2ResponseMsg=&Notes=Your merchant information is not correct.&User1=&User2=&User3=&User4=` this you have in one variable or it with html and inside body tag ?

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16683640/Screenshots/2012-11-23_1946.png

That is the view source of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = "<html>
        <body>TransID=0&REFNO=&Auth=&AVSCode=&CVV2ResponseMsg=&Notes=Your merchant information is not correct.&User1=&User2=&User3=&User4=
        </body>
    </html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $html ); //Lots of invalid html going on so I am suppressing the warnings
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$str = $xpath->query( '//body/text()')->item(0)->textContent;

parse_str( $str, $params );

print_r( $params );

/*

Array
(
    [TransID] => 0
    [REFNO] => 
    [Auth] => 
    [AVSCode] => 
    [CVV2ResponseMsg] => 
    [Notes] => Your merchant information is not correct.
    [User1] => 
    [User2] => 
    [User3] => 
    [User4] => 

)

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by standart php functions

```
 $cContent =    "<html>
   <body>TransID=0&REFNO=&Auth=&AVSCode=&CVV2ResponseMsg=&Notes=Your merchant information is not correct.&User1=&User2=&User3=&User4=
    </body>
</html>";

 echo $cContent = trim(strip_tags($cContent));


 parse_str($cContent, $aParams);

 print_r($aParams);
```